# Problem on connecting JDBC with sqlserver 2017

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to sqlserver 2017 using jdbc driver (microsoft 4.2 and 7.1) jdk 1.8_201. Windows 10

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS01;integratedSecurity=true;";
         Random r = new Random();
         try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
}
```

I got the following exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Connection reset by peer: socket write
>   error ClientConnectionId:16429365-183f-44fc-a599-c66fe7ad39be".   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2887)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1881)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2452)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   Autofill.main(Autofill.java:50) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>   ClientConnectionId:16429365-183f-44fc-a599-c66fe7ad39be   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:780)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:840)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:833)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1003)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:993)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1799)
>     ... 8 more

It is connected well with sqlcmd and SSMS, even though with Odbc

I cannot use Odbc driver since it is removed from jdk 8 and I don't have currently the old version 7 to connect with Odbc driver

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "trustServerCertificate=true;" to the connection string.

Answer (score -2):

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "USER", "PW");

I use mysql so I dont know how it works with sqlserver. (still learning it) But in mysql you have to specify a user and password. Maybe thats the problem.

LG
RT

Comment: The url of the sqlserver was working well before the latest updates
I reinstalled the sqlserver and have the same problemm

Comment: Have you tried :                                                                                  
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=DBName;integratedSecurity=true";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

Comment: Why do you think that posting the URL for MySQL would provide in any way an answer for Microsoft SQL Sever? In any case, when for SQL Server with `integratedSecurity`, the driver will authenticate with the current Windows user.

Comment: The exception is not mentioning to a bad credintial. It mentioned to an ssl problem where I don't know why since I installed everything as default